# How to detect if ancestor is focused in tvOS?

Tags: uikit, tvos

I have a custom `UIView` subclass and want to detect when its ancestor is in focus. But this class itself cannot be focused.

Basically, I want to do something similar to `UIImageView` when `adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused` is set to true.

I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't require the ancestor to communicate when focus changes.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the didUpdateFocusInContext and check if the target view is your ancestor:

```
  override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) 
  {
      if let target = context.nextFocusedView
         where self.isDescendantOfView(target)
      {
         // one of your ancestors has received focus 
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

We can't use `didUpdateFocus(in:with:)`, because it isn't called for all views of hierarchy, from the documentation:

> the focus engine calls this method on all focus environments that contain either the previously focused view, the next focused view, or both

So if the view return `false` for `canBecomeFocused`, this method can't be called on it.

The adequate way is to observe `UIFocusSystem.didUpdateNotification`, if you're using Combine it's something like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIFocusSystem.didUpdateNotification).sink { [weak self] notification in
    guard let context = notification.userInfo?[UIFocusSystem.focusUpdateContextUserInfoKey] as? UIFocusUpdateContext,
        let next = context.nextFocusedView, self?.isDescendant(of: next) ?? false else {
            print("is NOT descendant")
            return
    }

    print("is descendant")
}.store(in: &cancelBag)
```